# APNs Key (.p8 file) for Development/Sandbox

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to set up Apple Push Notifications (APNs) on my server, but I can't seem to figure out how to download a `.p8` file that's for a development environment. It's easy enough to register and download a `.p8` file, but there isn't an option to configure it for development/sandbox.

[image]

When using this key, I get a `400 -- BadDeviceToken` response from the APN server, which I've been led to believe means it's an environment mismatch. I was able to find a few tutorials that led me to register a Certificate instead, but in those cases, I ended up with a `.p12` file instead.

[image]

Any advice on this would be much appreciated. I'm running a Rails server, and using the [Apnotic gem](https://github.com/ostinelli/apnotic) to manage APNs. I'm happy to update to include my code if someone thinks that might be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

One p8 file should work for both sandbox and production builds